# Как вывести значение типа int для символа?

Tags: python, char, int

Я хочу попробовать вывести значение `int`/ASCII для `char` в Python. Как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужна функция [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord).

***Пример:***

```py
ord('A')  # 65
ord('Z')  # 90
```